# Angular Routing with templating

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

Imagine this scenario, you have a angular app (version 11) where the app.component call a feature module

```
app.component.html

<div class="content" fxFlex>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Inside my feature module I've a page split vertically into two (with a sideBar).

```
Component A Module X

| sideBar Z  | content A |

Component B Module X

| sideBar Z | content B|
```

The ideia is to change only the content when i navigate from A to B but without have to define the the sideBar Z into the components.

I think that I need to define some templating inside the routing. How can I achieve this behavior (I'm not finding this on documentation)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply move the sidebar to app-component..?

Comment: Because I'l have more than one module and the other modules can have different sidebar ou not have at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping your routes that require sidebar in navigation route

```
routes = [
...
{path: 'no-navigation-route', component: DComponent},
{
  path: '',
  component: NavigationComponent,
  children: [
     {path: 'path-a', component: ContentAComponent},
     {path: 'path-b', component: ContentBComponent}
  ],
}
]
```

here, you can put navigation inside of NavigationComponent and it should work exactly as described

Comment: Thanks a lot! A read mode about the children feature and I finally understand it =)